# How to format a number from thousands to K style

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

Ok,for example:

8408 to 8.4K ; 6735 to 6.7K ; 3090 to 3K

I'm using

```
    if (likes > 999 && likes <= 999999) {
        return Math.floor(likes / 1000) + "k";
    }
```

But it not working for me !

Please help me!
thanks !

Comment: OT: Is this code written in Javascript?

Comment: Do you get an error? What is it?

Comment: please specify the language and the output you are getting currently. And read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many (most?) languages allow you to format a number as a string with how many digits you'd like after the decimal point. Once you specify a language, I'll look into that.

In the meantime, note that currently you're just throwing away the digit after the decimal point.

You can instead do something like this:

```
return Math.floor(likes / 100) / 10.0 + "k";
```

If `likes` is an integer, you may not even need the `floor`:

```
return (likes / 100) / 10.0 + "k";
```

So it's `floor(6735 / 100) / 10.0` = `floor(67.35) / 10.0` = `67 / 10.0` = `6.7`.

Note that `3090` will get printed as `3.0k`. You may need a separate check (in addition to your current check) like:

```
if (likes / 100 % 10 == 0)
   return Math.floor(likes / 1000) + "k";
else
   return Math.floor(likes / 100) / 10.0 + "k";
```